# How to create a plot of power of test in R?

Tags: r, plot, normal-distribution, trend

I want to create a comparison for normal test with Shapiro-Wilks, Kolmogorov-Smirnov, Anderson-Darling, Cramer von Mises dan Adjusted Jarque-Bera methods based on the power of test (1-beta) on sample sizes n = 10,20,30,40 and 50.

```
testnormal=function(n,m,alfa)
{
require(nortest)
require(normtest)
require(xlsx)
pvalue=matrix(0,m,5)
decision=matrix(0,m,5)
for (i in 1:m)
{
data=runif(n,2,5)
test1=shapiro.test(data)
pv1=test1$p.value
pvalue[i,1]=pv1
if (pv1<alfa) 
{
decision[i,1]=1
}
test2=ks.test(data,"pnorm",mean=mean(data),sd=sd(data))
pv2=test2$p.value
pvalue[i,2]=pv2
if (pv2<alfa) 
{
decision[i,2]=1
}
test3=ad.test(data) 
pv3=test3$p.value
pvalue[i,3]=pv3
if (pv3<alfa) 
{
decision[i,3]=1
}
test4=cvm.test(data) 
pv4=test4$p.value
pvalue[i,4]=pv4
if (pv4<alfa) 
{ 
decision[i,4]=1
}
test5=ajb.norm.test(data) 
pv5=test5$p.value
pvalue[i,5]=pv5
if (pv2<alfa) 
{
decision[i,5]=1
}
}
result1=data.frame(pvalue)
result2=data.frame(decision)
colnames(result1)=c("SW","KS","AD","CvM","AJB")
colnames(result2)=c("SW","KS","AD","CvM","AJB")
write.xlsx(result1,"testnormal_pvalue.xlsx")
write.xlsx(result2,"testnormal_decision.xlsx")
one_min_beta=t(1-(colSums(decision)/m))
test.of.power=data.frame(one_min_beta)
colnames(test.of.power)=c("SW","KS","AD","CvM","AJB")
return(test.of.power)
}
simulation=testnormal(10,100,0.05)
simulation2=testnormal(20,100,0.05)
simulation3=testnormal(30,100,0.05)
simulation4=testnormal(40,100,0.05)
simulation5=testnormal(50,100,0.05)
output=rbind(simulation,simulation2,simulation3,simulation4,simulation5)
output
```

I want to graph the power of the test to see trends in the up and down trend of the power of the test over the sample size, anyone can help please?

Answer (score 1):

I went through your code and rewrote along the way to better understand what you want (what is the excel stuff for?). I have broken it down to smaller functions to allow you to have more control in these kinds of simulation studies. The code is not particularly efficient.

But does this give you what you want?

```
library("nortest")
library("normtest")
library("dplyr")
library("ggplot2")

# Function for doing all tests and putting it into a data.frame
tests <- function(data) {
  list_of_tests <- list(
    SW = shapiro.test(data),
    KS = ks.test(data, pnorm, mean = mean(data), sd = sd(data)),
    AD = ad.test(data) ,
    CMV = cvm.test(data),
    AJB = ajb.norm.test(data)
  )
  # Combine to tibble
  res <- bind_rows(lapply(list_of_tests, unclass))
  res[c("method", "p.value")] # Keep only method and p-value cols
}
# Test it with e.g. 'tests(data = runif(8, 2, 5))'

# Function for repeated simulation and testing, combine results and derive power
testnormal <- function(n, m, alpha) {
  # Important that runif is inside replicate
  test_res <- 
    bind_rows(replicate(tests(data = runif(n, 2, 5)), n = m, 
              simplify = FALSE))

  test_of_powers <-
    test_res %>% 
    group_by(method)  %>% 
    summarize(power = mean(p.value < alpha)) %>% 
    mutate(n = n, m = m, alpha = alpha)
    
  return(test_of_powers)
}

# Repeat over a number of simulations:
sims <- expand.grid(n = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50),
                    m = 1000,
                    alpha = 0.05)

output <- bind_rows(
  mapply(testnormal, n = sims$n, m = sims$m, alpha = sims$alpha,
         SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
)
```

Actually doing the plot:

```
# Plot it
ggplot(output, aes(x = n, y = power, col = method)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

This way should make it easier to plot as well as making simulations over other grids of values (e.g. varying alpha) or expand your range of `n`, etc.

Comment: This is the result in my pc:

`Error in UseMethod("depth") : 
  no applicable method for 'depth' applied to an object of class "NULL"
Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_upviewport, as.integer(n)) : 
  cannot pop the top-level viewport ('grid' and 'graphics' output mixed?)`

The plot is great by the way.
But anyway i need to create the table to see the comparison between this methods according to the sample size

Comment: When does this error occur? I think you need to run it in a clean R session and post the output of `sessionInfo()`. In regards to the table, is suppose everything you want is contained in the `output` object.